# Running time analysis of Dijkstra's for shortest path algorithm but with a maximum K stops

Tags: algorithm

For a problem like this (https://leetcode.com/problems/cheapest-flights-within-k-stops/), I can solve this problem with Dijkstra's algorithm with an upper bound of O(|E| + |V|log|V|).

However, since there is an additional stopping criteria of max of K stops. My upper bound should be less if K < V.

Q: How do I incorporate the K stops into my analysis of Dijkstra's algorithm?

Q2: What if we assume the graph is fully connected (Each vertex is connected every other vertices. So E = V^2)? Does this change the analysis?

Comment: Your upper bound may not be less if K < V. The K sets an upper limit on the number of edges you can travel per path, but doesn't limit the number of paths. If all nodes remain within K from the starting node, your time complexity doesn't change at all - you still have to visit every edge and every node. I think that your time complexity will stay the same.

Comment: @Primusa What if we assume the graph is fully connected (Each vertex is connected every other vertices. So E = V^2)? Does this change the analysis?

Comment: If the graph is fully connected every edge is accessible from your starting node after one step. Unless K == 1 in which case your time complexity becomes `O(|V|)`, you will still visit every edge and every node.

Comment: @Primusa Can you see the answer below and see if you have any comments?

Comment: I mean if you click the link and view solutions the faster of the two sample accepted solutions is dijkstra's which runs in `O(E+nlogn)`. As I said before, K isn't a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't work for this problem.  Once it finds the cheapest path to a vertex, it won't look for any other paths... but the cheapest path to a vertex may use up too many slots to allow the cheapest path from there to the target.  It could be that a more expensive path to an intermediate vertex is the best one if it leaves more stops available to reach the target.

For example:

```
S--1--A--1--B--1--C--1--T
 \         / \         /
  `---4---'   `---9---'
```

In this example, the cheapest path from S to T with 2 stops is `S-B-C-T` with cost 6.  But Dijkstra's algorithm with limited stops will only find `S-A-B-T` with cost 11.

Off the top of my head, the best algorithm I know for this problem takes O(KE) time.

Comment: For this problem, once it find the cheapest path as long as it is within K stops. It will be the correct answer. If after K stops, it still cannot find an answer, the correct answer will be -1 (which is basically saying there is not a valid answer)

Comment: Try it on the example I provided.

Comment: In your example what is the K stop limit?

Comment: 2 stops (i.e., 3 edges)

Comment: Dijstra's will correctly find the answer `S-B-C-T` because once you find T, you put that back into the priority queue No?

For your example, let's say K is 100. The answer would be the same which is `SBCT`

Comment: @samol, I believe you miss the point. How the Dijkstra will prefer the direct `S-B` (4) path over the shorter but indirect `S-A-B` (2) one? And if you went `S-A-B`, you must use `B-T` (9) instead of much shorter `B-C-T` (2) because you run out of stops which gives you a total of 11 instead of 6.

Comment: Ah, you did not try it, and I think that you are not reading what I write, so I am disinclined to write more.  With K=100 the best path is SABCT with cost 4.

Comment: Ok sorry. I will run your example in code and study a bit more before commenting further. I am starting to see the problem with dijkstra's

Comment: @MattTimmermans I have tried your example. However, using dijkstra's I am able to get the correct answer of 6 (`S-B-C-T`). I included my solution here: http://tpcg.io/6Lz2cw

Comment: @samoi you didn't implement the 'decrease key' operation, or anything equivalent.  Instead you left both paths to C in your queue and extended them both.  Your algorithm will find the right path, but it's not Dijkstra's and doesn't have the same complexity.

Comment: @samoi in fact the algorithm you implemented has exponential complexity.  Maybe you tried to use it and that's why you think Dijkstra's takes too long?  Anyway, I fixed it here: http://tpcg.io/8qYS59 to do standard dijkstra.  If you uncomment the "Layered Dijkstra" line, it turns into a new algorithm the *will* work for your problem, but runs much faster.

Comment: Ahh. The decrease key operation means that you mark the node as visited. I had an incorrect understanding of Dijkstra's. So what is the running time with the layered dijkstra's. I assume it is no longer O(E + ElogE)?

Comment: Marking the node visited is not exactly the same as Dijkstra's decrease_key, but it accomplishes pretty much the same thing.  The layered version is like running Dijkstra's algorithm in a graph made of k copies (layers) of the original graph.  As such it takes O(KE log E) time in the worst case.

Comment: Did you mean O(K V log V)? As you will visit each vertex up to K times?

Comment: You can visit each vertex up to K times, and each time you traverse all its edges.. Oh, and actually you can have K entries in the priority queue for each edge, so O(KE log KE)

Comment: @MattTimmermans I learned a lot from this conversation. Do you mind summarizing it and add the discussion about the modified dijkstra's into your answer?

Comment: Actually I thought about this more. You visit each vertex up to K times. You visit all the edges up to K times as well. Which means the size of priority queue is up to (K * V) so each heap operation costs log(KV).. And there will be KE heappush and KV heappop.  Therefore it should be O(KElog(KV) + KVlog(KV)) = O(K(E + V)log(KV)) - http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61bl/r//cur/graphs/dijkstra-algorithm-runtime.html?topic=lab24.topic&step=4&course=